# Hibernate search : use Elastic Search decay_function in spatial() query?

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-search

I have different fields to make a query from, like a title, a text, and a location. I want to put more weight on the location field. I found the decay_function from Elastic Search, which exactly answers my needs according to this example : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_detailed_example .
However the system i'm on uses Hibernate Search queries. I found the Spatial ( https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#spatial ) filter, but is there a way to replace the "within()" by the decay_function ? Or by a personnalized function or something like that ?

I know I could use the within() but it means I would have to define specific ranges. It could work but it's not the optimal solution in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using the DSL itself (for now, it will be possible in 6 to integrate native predicates in the DSL).

But you can create a native Elasticsearch query for this specific case as explained in our documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_queries :

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
QueryDescriptor query = ElasticsearchQueries.fromJson(
    "{ 'query': { 'match' : { 'lastName' : 'Brand' } } }");
List<?> result = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(query, GolfPlayer.class).getResultList();
```

This way you can use whatever Elasticsearch construct you see fit. And you can still use the DSL for the other supported queries.

Unrelated to your question: I saw you are a student, are you using Hibernate Search for a school project? It would be nice having Search taught in a French school :).

Comment: No i'm currently using it at my internship ~ Yes i agree with this; elastic+hibernate is fun and I had several shcool projects during the year where we could have used it. However I guess the year's program is already heavy so teachers have to make choices and take some shortcuts to focus on some points during a lesson.
By the way, the solution seems to work, but i'm struggling with the syntax. I'll solve the question when it'll work without erros!

Comment: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ might help if you're writing the JSON manually. The other option is to use a JSON library to write it. You don't need it in your case but keep in mind that, if you need it, you can also obtain the underlying Elasticsearch client and do whatever you want with it: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-client-access . This might be useful for aggregations as we don't expose anything for it right now.

Comment: Managed to get the syntax right, but now I have a problem with the 'scale' field. As in the example, I put "30km" but all I get is a number_format_exception. It must be because instead of using a Geo_Point, I have the attributes Double latitude and Double longitude in my object (next to title, text and everything). So I used twice the gauss decay function, once on the latitude, once on the longitude (not sure it works like this but not the problem for now). + I indexed these fields with (at)Longitude and (at)Latitude, however is it still useful as I call ES with ElasticsearchQueries.fromJson?

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a Geo_Point because I would have to change the database table thus refactor a lot of code everywhere. But I can't figure out any solution but this.